# err_name_not_resolved Win7 Error

Tags: apache, google-chrome, windows-7, dns, windows-server-2012

I am facing a strange issue on a single PC, all other PC's I have tried are fine so the problem definitely seems localised to this setup.

- Windows 7
- Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.82 m

I have developed a simple website on an Apace web server (Windows Server 2012), and assigned it an internal IP address (`1.2.3.4`), and internal dns name (`MyWebsite.MyDomain`).

This website is only available within our company. When I type the URL `MyWebsite.MyDomain` into any browser I am presented with the correct web page, great. When I type the IP address `1.2.3.4` into any browser I am also presented with the correct web page, great again.

This is the case for every PC I have tried so far, **apart from one**. Instead I am presented with the following error message;

> This web page is not available
>
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Why would this be?

Things I have tried so far on the local PC;

- delete history/cache on local PC
- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /renew
- ipconfig /registerdns
- changed to Google public dns (`8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4`)
- restart (multiple times)
- tried IE and FFOX (same error)
- checked hosts file (all looks ok)

The only change I ever made to this individual PC was I installed XAMPP and changed the hosts file (for testing purposes). I have since uninstalled XAMPP and reverted to the original hosts file - could this be the issue? I can't think of any other changes.

I had thought the issue was with my web server setup, but as the web site is accessible from all other PC's it would appear not?

Looks like a re-build may be necessary for this PC, unless somebody can perhaps point me to another suggestion? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That machine doesn't happen to have any static ip addressing configured, does it?  I'm thinking that perhaps a manual entry for DNS server is conflicting or overriding what DHCP is supposed to be assigning.